# colour scheme depends on '''chmod'''

Tags: shell, terminal

**Edit**

I changed the permission level (`chmod`) for files and I cannot distinguish them on my terminal because it doesn't show a different colour scheme based on the type of permission.

How should I set my terminal to be able to distinguish based on a colour scheme?

Comment: `:colo pablo`, and there are a lot more preset palettes.

Comment: Given your tags, I'm assuming you want to change the color of the filename displayed on your vim screen?

Comment: Color depends on many things, the editor you are using, the terminal. There is no metadata about *color* for a file in the filesystem, the colors you see are part of the representation being done by the combination of aforementioned systems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From one of your statements:

> I presume the colour scheme is depends on the permission of accessing the file.

I think you are talking about the `--color=auto` option for `ls`, which is often added by default in a lot of Linux flavors with lines like this in their `.profile` or `.bashrc` files:

```
alias ls='ls --color=auto'
alias ll='ls -al --color=auto'
```

This option can output helpful coloration to a terminal, typically based on file permissions and if the item is a symlink or directory. This behavior can vary based on what terminal `ls` is connected to and what color options are set for `ls`. Below are some screenshots of some test directories and files I set up to show this:

No colors:

[image: no colors]

`--color=auto` set, strict file permissions:

[image: no perms]

`--color=auto` set, open file permissions:

[image: all perms]

The above examples used the `st` terminal with `bash`.

The colors that `ls` uses are specified in the `LS_COLORS` environment variable, which you check by `echo`-ing it and change by `export`-ing it. As said before, common coloration differences are for file permissions and directories/symlinks, but can be customized for pretty much anything. An example of this are the 300+ custom filetype colors in [this GitHub project](https://github.com/trapd00r/LS_COLORS), and a list of potential options for `LS_COLORS` entries can be found on this [AskUbuntu answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/466203/1002091).